# PHP causing high SQL load

Tags: php, mysql, load, flush

I need to import 70,000 entries from a csv into the SQL database. This unfortunately is causing an extremely high server load and eventually crashing the server. I was reading this article about mass SQL imports http://naleid.com/blog/2009/10/01/batch-import-performance-with-grails-and-mysql/ and it mentioned that flushing is required 'The easiest way to deal with this is to create a simple method to clear out these collections periodically.'

That then runs the script extremely quickly, and although it is in another language is there a PHP alternative? Either for flushing or garbage collection. What would be the best way to import 70,000 entries in one loop?

The article also mentions using MySQL indexes to reduce load, how do I approach this in PHP too?

Thanks

P.s Also do you think it is SQL or is it the CSV reader?

Comment: What kind of records are you importing? 70.000 isn't alot. Have you checked http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html?

Comment: I am importing entries from a csv document, so it grabs the line the enters in into the given tables.

Comment: 70,000 is not lot. in fact, you can split 1 csv into more n upload them

Comment: Also I am modifying the data after reading and before importing

Comment: What's the size of the CSV file? And how much time it takes to import?

Comment: the file is ~5mb do you think it could be the CSV file causing load not MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

You can try next:

Do a **TableShadowCopy**. (if it is live table, this way you will avoid site hang, else you can skip this step)

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS __shadow_table; // droping previous shadow table if exists
CREATE TABLE __shadow_table LIKE table; // COPY source table structue
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS __shadow_table SELECT * FROM table; // possible use of WHERE statemnet
```

Now you have exact copy of your source table and you can do with it what you need not worrying about consequences of "site down" while importing.

**DISABLE indexes** on the newly created table

```
ALTER TABLE __shadow_table DISABLE KEYS;
```

Now you can do your import to the table (`__shadow_table`).

Try `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` (requires `FILE` permission)

If you have **no** `FILE` permission use `BULK INSERT`

```
INSERT INTO __shadow_table (col1, col2, col3, col4) VALUES (1,2,3,4), (6,7,8,9), (20,30,40,60);
```

**ENABLE indexes** on the table (shadow table)

```
ALTER TABLE __shadow_table ENABLE KEYS;
```

**DROP** original table

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table
```

**RENAME** shadow table to the original (`DROP`ped) name

```
RENAME TABLE __shadow_table TO table;
```

Disabling indexes while import allows to decrease the load and HDD searches when inserting data. Also if table is `InnoDB`, `FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS` should be disabled to.
Everything what was **disabled** during import should be **enabled** by the end of the import.

Comment: You are Welcome! We've developed and using similar technique in our Live environment and it is working very smooth. Very huge data amounts + No service interruption. That's what you get.